# Using command line arguments in python rather than shell

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Assume a python script is callable with:

```
python myscript.py ./mycommand > myoutput.txt
```

How do I make sure that `myscript.py` gets `./mycommand > myoutput.txt` in the list of command line arguments rather than the shell piping the output of `python myscript.py ./mycommand` to the file?

EDIT

Using quotes poses additional problems. Consider:

```
import subprocess
import sys

argList = sys.argv[1].split()

subprocess.call(argList)
```

which is then called by:

```
python myscript.py 'ls -l > ls.out'
```

results in

```
ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ls.out: No such file or directory
```

The motivation is that only the output from the command I am trying to run should be saved in the file. Any other output from `myscript.py` to `stdout` shouldn't go to the file. It would appear that the pipe needs to be set with the `stdout` option to `subprocess.call()`. Is there a way to use the list of arguments directly so I don't have to parse it for things like `>`, `2>`, `2&>`, `<` etc?

Comment: Yes, quotes will do it but is there a way to do it without quotes?

Comment: Without quotes, the `> myoutput.txt` is not part of the command-line arguments to python (in typical shells).

Comment: @tpg2114 What could possibly be a cleaner or simpler solution? Is there something wrong with quotes?

Comment: I was wondering if there was a cleaner or simpler solution. The cleaner/simpler solution would be if quotes weren't needed.

Comment: If you want to do something with myoutput.txt other than send it the stdout from your python script, then `>` is not the construct you want in the first place.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the intent and the issue with using quotes.

Comment: why not use the argparse module and define your own -pipe command and -forward command ? tbh not sure why you would want to overload > ... and no you cant use it directly because of how bash calls things... I guess you could write your own shell that passes it as command line args...

Comment: The idea is to make it as natural as possible for users to pre-pend their original command with the launcher script... our users struggle constructing normal command line arguments, so the more different this is the more headaches I will have.

Comment: why not use the logging module for your script output that you want to see and normal stdout for the program results...basically you are making the biggest headache trying to overload this operator... the hours cost in terms of what you want to do is huge...

Comment: What is the purpose of `myscript.py`? Cleaner argument validation, permissions checks, something else entirely?  (If users have trouble with the normal shell commands what is this "subshell" adding that makes it better for them?)  There may be a better way to achieve what you want at a much lower level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard bash or tcsh shell will parse the command you give it itself, and interpret certain special characters as direction to the shell process itself (the ">" character in your example).  The called program has no control over this; the command line parsing happens before your program is called.

In your example, you could say:

```
python myscript.py ./mycommand ">" myoutput.txt
```

And the quoted ">" will tell the shell not to use its special behavior.

The subprocess module has two modes of operation; one with a shell (typically /bin/sh) intermediate process -- this is when you give the `Popen` object a `shell=True` keyword argument.  When you invoke it in this way, it invokes the shell to parse the argument text, and then the shell invokes the command you specified as a subprocess-once-removed from your program.

The other mode of operation, the default, is when `shell=False`.  This creates a subprocess and populates its ARGV array directly without any intermediate shell trying to interpret the characters in your command.

The end result is, if you want to issue a command from a shell that interprets special characters, and include special characters, you have to escape them or quote them. If you're invoking a subprocess from the `subprocess` standard library module, you can pass in arbitrary text as the elements of the subprocess-to-be's ARGV, and not worry about them being interpreted in some special way by an intermediary shell process.

Comment: Came by this answer and I'm not sure what you mean by the last paragraph... when I do `subprocess.call("cat foo.txt && touch foo.bar".split()) it assumes that I'm passing everything else an an argument to cat. So when you say you can pass in arbitrary text as the elements of a subprocess-to-be's ARGV, you don't mean you can pass an arbitrary shell command?

Comment: `subprocess.call("cat foo.txt && touch foo.bar".split())` would launch the program `cat` and its ARGV would be populated by the literal strings `"foo.txt", "&&", "touch", "foo.bar"`. The program `cat` assumes positional arguments are files and would be confused -- is there a file named `"&&"` in the current directory? Alternatively, `subprocess.call("cat foo.txt && touch foo.bar", shell=True)` would launch `/bin/sh` to interpret the command, and to it, the `&&` has a special meaning (evaluate command next if command previous had exit code 0).

Comment: Thanks, good to know - I didn't understand exactly what the docs meant by shell=True but this is pretty clear. How do I get the output of the command though?

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to take on a dependency you could use [Kenneth Reitz's `envoy`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) (you'll still need to use quotes if you want to pass arbitrary commands to your script from the command line).

```
from envoy import run
from sys import argv

run(argv[1])
```

And then you could invoke it using:

```
$ python myscript.py './mycommand > myoutput.txt'
```

Alternately, if you want shell-like syntax in your Python files you could use [`sh`](https://github.com/amoffat/sh) (formerly `pbs`) or [`plumbum`](https://github.com/tomerfiliba/plumbum):

```
from sh import ls

with open("myoutput.txt", "w") as outfile:
    ls("-l", _out=outfile)

# Or, in plumbum
from plumbum.cmd import ls

# Yes, this looks crazy, but the docs say it works.
ls["-l"] > "myoutput.txt"
```